# Yeoman crashes after first input

Tags: javascript, yeoman

My install of yeoman keeps on crashing after selecting an item from the initial menu.  For example if I select Install a generator it shows the correct response but then does not respond to any input and just hangs. Note that no errors are thrown.

I think this may be some issue with inquire.js however I am not sure how to go about trying to find the root of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem. I recently updated to Sierra osx... wondering if there may be a Terminal bug with Sierra?

My "yo" stats:

```
$ yo --version && echo $PATH $NODE_PATH && node -e 'console.log(process.platform, process.versions)' && cat Gruntfile.js
2.0.0
/Users/USERNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/Users/USERNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/bin:/Users/USERNAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/USERNAME/.rvm/bin
darwin { http_parser: '2.7.0',
  node: '8.1.0',
  v8: '5.8.283.41',
  uv: '1.12.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  modules: '57',
  openssl: '1.0.2l',
  icu: '59.1',
  unicode: '9.0',
  cldr: '31.0.1',
  tz: '2017b' }
cat: Gruntfile.js: No such file or directory
```

Comment: There may be but I am running on windows.